# EXCEL/VBA: Column header and values are offset, how to get them synchronized

Tags: regex, excel, vba, vlookup

I am using an output file (CSV) wich is coming from an external source - used to do data scraping.

However, web pages that are "scrapped" doesn't have the same exaction pattern, so in the output file (Excel), I have column that are offset. Fortunaltly, the values contains the name of the header , so I am looking a solution to solve the "offset" problem.

PS: Some rows are offset, some not. The offset can be by 1, 2 or more cell, so i can't do: value(i+1)  = i as there is no logic

Download File [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/omnu1452pmv4o98/SORTcannodale2013.csv), or same info here:

```
FRAME           BRAKES         SADDLE         WHEELS          etc….
brakes: info1   saddle:info1   wheels:info1     
frame:info2     brakes:info2   saddle:info2   wheels: info2 
brakes: info3   saddle:info3   wheels:info3
```

I dont know if vlookUp, combined with some regex could do the trick,

What do you suggest ?

EDIT: 
Download File [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/omnu1452pmv4o98/SORTcannodale2013.csv)

VBA CODE

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim Titles As Variant
Dim Data As Variant
Dim Dataline As String
Dim NumDataPoints As Long
Dim FirstTitle As String
Dim WhichTitle As Long
Dim Offset As Long
Dim rowcount As Long

Open "SORTcannodale2013.csv" For Input As #1

Line Input #1, Dataline

Titles = Split(Dataline, ",")
For Offset = 0 To UBound(Titles)
    Cells(1, Offset + 1) = Titles(Offset)
Next

rowcount = 2
'While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, Dataline
    Data = Split(Dataline, Chr$(34) & "," & Chr$(34))

    FirstTitle = LCase(Left(Data(0), InStr(Data(0), vbLf) - 1))
    For WhichTitle = 0 To UBound(Titles)
        If Titles(WhichTitle) = FirstTitle Then Exit For
    Next
    For Offset = WhichTitle To UBound(Titles)
        Cells(rowcount, Offset + 1) = Data(Offset - WhichTitle)
    Next
    rowcount = rowcount + 1
'Wend

Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: are you creating the CSV file, or is it coming from some other data source

Comment: Coming from other data source unfortunatly.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way I could come up with was to read the CSV file in, and write it out to the spreadsheet myself.

I read the first line to get the titles.

I then read the second line, and inspect the first piece of data. I then compare this to the titles to get my offset.

I then write out the data, using the offset I have

Loop through the file until I get to the end, and quit.

This will always start writing in A1 on the current sheet. I'll leave it as an exercise to get it to write elsewhere

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim Titles As Variant
Dim Data As Variant
Dim Dataline As String
Dim NumDataPoints As Long
Dim FirstTitle As String
Dim WhichTitle As Long
Dim Offset As Long
Dim rowcount As Long

Open "test.csv" For Input As #1

Line Input #1, Dataline
Titles = Split(Dataline, ",")
For Offset = 0 To UBound(Titles)
    Cells(1, Offset + 1) = Titles(Offset)
Next

rowcount = 2
While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, Dataline
    Data = Split(Dataline, ",")
    FirstTitle = UCase(Left(Data(0), InStr(Data(0), ":") - 1))
    For WhichTitle = 0 To UBound(Titles)
        If Titles(WhichTitle) = FirstTitle Then Exit For
    Next
    For Offset = WhichTitle To UBound(Titles)
        Cells(rowcount, Offset + 1) = Data(Offset - WhichTitle)
    Next
    rowcount = rowcount + 1
Wend

Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: The offset is not linear, as some values are missing in certain rows. So the offset could be =1 in the start...but could be =2 in the middle of the row,  Calculating the offset would'nt work, the data that we can use to link the cell to its "good position" would be with a regex

Comment: then, as you have all the data in the `Data()` array, you can extract the title with the `UCase(Left(Data(x), InStr(Data(x), ":") - 1))` function, and then use that to decide where to put it

Comment: I tried it, and I have a problem. My csv is in this form "header","header2" \n "header:value","header:value2" .... so when I split with the comma... it doesnt find a match...

Comment: And cell values may contain commas, so splitting by the comma doesnt do the trick

Comment: if all are quoted, split by the `"` and read every other value (horrible hack)

Comment: Splitting by " gives me an error because of the left() function applied a "comma" (caused by separating values by " ) . I am desesperate... I thing that regex is the way to go

Comment: the other way I can think of doing that would be to search `Dataline` for the title, then use `startpos=instr(ucase(dataline),title)+len(title)+1` then use that to extract the data with `mid(dataline,startpos,instr(startpos,dataline,"""")-startpos)`

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason to write your own CSV import function here. The file uploaded to DropBox has the fields enclosed in double-quotes and any double-quotes within the fields are correctly doubled up.

To get the file into Excel is as simple as:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="SORTcannodale2013.csv", _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Comma:=True
```

The header row doesn't actually have entries for all possible values. For example, "Rear Shock" and "Extras" are in the test data but are not represented in the header row. You should identify all possible values and construct your own header row that contains all of them.

Within each data entry, we have the field name then an embedded line feed (ASCII character 10) and then the data value. Splitting the entry into field name and value would just entail using the `Split` function as before with `Chr$(10)` as the delimiter.

Turning the data into a usable worksheet can be done by simply hardcoding the column number for each field name (e.g. in a `Dictionary` object), splitting out the field name from each entry, looking up the appropriate column number in the dictionary and outputting the data value to the appropriate cell.

If you are going to have an ongoing need to process this data then it may well be worth investing the time to convert it into a more standardised format (e.g. XML). Nothing in the data is particularly suited to being processed in Excel. To turn it into XML, you would need to do some more work on escaping some of the characters in the data. If you then needed to use Excel then it would be easy enough to import the XML data